# Custom ~/.inputrc definitions not sourcing correctly?

Tags: bash

I have the following in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off

# To use these in ITerm2 you may also need to configure preferences to send the correct escape
# code for the key combination.

# Option + Arrows to jump words.
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word


# The following are other escape sequences that can be configured in Iterm2 preferences.
#        ESC ^H   Delete previous word (backspace key) [n]
#        ESC DEL  Delete previous word (delete key) [n]
#        ESC SP   Set the mark (space key); see ^X^X and ^Y above
#        ESC .    Get the last (or [n]'th) word from previous line
#        ESC ?    Show possible completions; see below
#        ESC <    Move to start of history
#        ESC >    Move to end of history
#        ESC b    Move backward a word [n]
#        ESC d    Delete word under cursor [n]
#        ESC f    Move forward a word [n]
#        ESC l    Make word lowercase [n]
#        ESC u    Make word uppercase [n]
#        ESC y    Yank back last killed text
#        ESC v    Show library version
#        ESC w    Make area up to mark yankable
#        ESC nn   Set repeat count to the number nn
#        ESC C    Read from environment variable ``_C_'', where C is
#                 an uppercase letter
```

However, when I source, this is what happens:

```
me (~/Desktop) $ . ~/.inputrc
-bash: \e[1;5C:: command not found
-bash: \e[1;5D:: command not found
```

What gives?

EDIT: Also on iTerm2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.inputrc` is not a shell script; it is a configuration file used by the Readline library, which `bash` uses. You can re-read the file using by typing <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> (the default binding for the `re-read-init-file` Readline function).

The benefit of putting key bindings in `.inputrc` is that this file is read by *any* program that uses Readline, not just `bash`. You can put bindings in your `.bashrc` using the `bind` command.

```
bind '"\e[1;5C": forward-word'
```

(Of course, such bindings will *only* be available in `bash`.)

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I have these entries in my `.inputrc`; `"\e[A": history-search-backward`, `"\e[B": history-search-forward`. Sometimes when I log in or load a terminal window, they do not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? The bindings in `.inputrc`, or `bind` commands in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Normally, the bindings I listed in my `.inputrc` work. Occasionally, I log in and they do not work anymore. I am trying to figure out how to get them working again inside a session where they have stopped working. As you suggested, I hit 'Control + x' followed by 'Control + r' but nothing changed, the .inputrc entries are still not working. If I log out & back in, they still do not work. Eventually they will start working again some day on their own but I would rather it start working right now.

Comment: I have moved this to its own question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1381065/inputrc-bindings-sporadically-not-working), thanks